# How to use asp:Login and asp:CreateUserWizard on Same Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, zurb-foundation-5

I want to place two Zurb Foundation 5.5.2 modals on the same page.  One modal contains a customized `<asp:Login>` and the other contains a customized `<asp:CreateUserWizard>`.

I've created two separate user controls for this purpose.  Independently, they work great. However, when I try to place both of them on the same page I either get a `KeyError` or the user can't login.

The problem is that the `ID="UserName"` and `ID="Password"` are required for both the `<asp:Login>` and `<asp:CreateUserWizard>`.

There is custom ASPX similar to this inside of each of these ASP element tags.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />   
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
```

Obviously, I can't have identical / clashing IDs on the same page, but ASP.NET expects to find an ID of `UserName` and `Password` inside of `<asp:Login>` and `<asp:CreateUserWizard>`.

I tried changing the `Password` ID inside `<asp:Login>` like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Password_Different_ID" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
```

and I get an error.

```
LoginUserModal: LayoutTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID Password for the password.
```

I did the same thing for `<asp:CreateUserWizard>` and I get.

```
CreateUserWizard1: CreateUserWizardStep.ContentTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID Password for the new password, this is required if AutoGeneratePassword = true.
```

I set `AutoGeneratePassword="false"`, and I get the exact same error message even though I set it to `false`.

Any idea on how to change these IDs, or another way to solve the problem?